# Get returned value from async function using async library

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

So, i'm using express locals to create custom function. I have this:

```
Menu.getMenu(function(err, menu) {
    app.locals.buildMenuStructure = function(){
        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            ids.push(menu[i]._id); 
        }
        return ids;
    };
});
```

But the problem is that when i add some data to Menu collection the function doesn't know about menu being populated. To see new ids i need to restart the server.

Now i realized that i need to retrieve menus inside `buildMenuStructure` function to see effect immediately. In that case i need to get the value of `getMenu` asynchronous function and return it. Something like this:

```
app.locals.buildMenuStructure = function(){
         var ids = [];
         Menu.getMenu(function(err, menu) {
              for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
                  ids.push(menu[i]._id); 
              }
         });
         return ids;
}
```

I plan to use async library for that but i can't make it work(( 
Note! This functions are simplified. 
`Menu.getMenu` function is the same as mongoose `Menu.find({});`

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to synchronously retrieve the value of asynchronous function, but is's impossible (unless you're using fibers).

The best solution for you is to keep your original code, but to move it into express middleware and use `res.locals` instead of `app.locals`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  Menu.getMenu(function(err, menu) {
    res.locals.buildMenuStructure = function(){
      var ids = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        ids.push(menu[i]._id); 
      }
      return ids;
    };
    next(err);
  });
})
```

In this case `buildMenuStructure` helper will be built anew for every new request.

[Here is an example of using both `app.locals` and `res.locals` in `express` with `ejs` engine](https://gist.github.com/lbeschastny/8687591).

Comment: I don't have res, req since it's app.locals function. I'm using it in ejs template. And i want to use it anywhere in the site without requests.

Comment: I can't see why you don't want to use `res.locals` instead of `app.locals`. It'll be available to your `ejs` template as well. The only difference is that `res.locals` are scoped to the request and `app.locals` while `app.locals` are global to the whole application.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. This is the error - buildMenuStructure is not defined.